# django static folder name change

Tags: python, django, static

My django project is located at `c:/django/project` and static folder is at `c:/django/project/app/static`. I put bootstrap and jquery files to my template under `link href="/static/` and `src="/static/`. But if i change name of folder with static files, they become unavailable. I tried to change `settings.py` settings and here is the code, but it isn't help also.

`STATIC_URL = '/static/`

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/django/lingsite/inputs/static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static/')`

Where static files folder is defined?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

this is correct way to locate static files:

```
{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}
```

But anyway, you have a misconfigured paths:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: it is the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the static files get *served* too.

During development the easiest way is put `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS` then the `runserver` command will automatically serve your static files. Follow the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) for other methods, and a pointer to the `collectstatic` command you use for deployment in production.